# Parcel Buffer - Property Setbacks

Tags: buffer, parcel

I am trying to model property line setbacks. In this case: 25 ft from front and back of property, 10 ft from one side and 8 ft from the other. Tried averaging the total set back distance 68/4 = 17 ft from each side. However this does not produce the same result as the specified setbacks. Typically off by 100-200 sq. ft.

Are there any tools similar to buffer that will model the specific setbacks. I could identify the centroids and somehow specify from there, or use the street centerlines.

Comment: what software are you using?

Comment: What is the desired result? Do you just want an area figure, or do you actually want to show the allowed building envelope? Centroids won't do you any good, and centerlines will only help to identify the front vs side lines. There are a few questions here that are related, and most go the route of converting the polygons to lines and then buffering the lines to get the different setbacks. Thrown in there is determining what is a front vs side vs rear line.